# How to transfer complete videos between Youtube accounts?

Tags: youtube, transfer

I have following problem. I have changed my service name and now have a different youtube account. I would like to transfer all of my videos along with rating and comments from that old account to the new one, is this possible?

Regardz,
Mladjo

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible. You must re-upload everything. 
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2404846?hl=en

Comment: Check this instruction: http://www.alicekeeler.com/teachertech/2013/07/08/copying-a-youtube-video-to-another-youtube-account/
1. Go to the video manager.
2. Check the checkbox next to the video.
3. From the actions menu choose creative commons.
4. Go to the video. Right click on the video to “copy the video URL”.
6. Log into other YouTube account.
7. Paste the URL of the video into the address bar (ie. go to the video logged in under new account).
8. Under the video is the option to “remix this video.” Note this only shows up if the video is under a creative commons license.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas Thank you for that great advice!! That's awesome!

Comment: @SQLGeorge This might work, but I think it won't keep the original comments and the views count...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, but unfortunately all you can do is download the videos from your old account and re-upload it to the new one. It is really tiring specially if you have a lot of videos and everything will restart as well (view count etc..).

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2404846?hl=en